# Работа с данными из GET запроса

Tags: javascript, get

Делаю запрос:

```js
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "https://site.ru/api/sss.php?token=1234&device=111", true);
x.onload = function (){
    alert(x.responseText);
}
x.send(null);
```

Получаю ответ: `{"mid":"0","id_1":123,"id":111}`

Как в дальнейшем работать с ответом? Необходимо получить из него значение после `mid`, а именно "0" и использовать его в условиях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как по ключу:

```js
let mess = {"mid":"0","id_1":123,"id":111};
console.log(mess["mid"])
```

Но еще зависит от типа данных, которые вы имеете_ возможно необходимо будет использовать `JSON.parse`

```js
let mess = '{"mid":"0","id_1":123,"id":111}';
let mesJson = JSON.parse(mess);
let mid = mesJson["mid"];
if (mid == 0) {
  console.log("mid равен нулю");
} else {
  console.log("mid равен: " + mid);
}
```

**UPD**
Переменную `mess` я определил, исходя их ваших данных, которые есть у вас в вопросе. Т.е. значения, которые я туда поместил - это просто пример данных, которые вы получаете при вашем `GET`-запросе. Очевидно, что данные могут быть и другие, т.е. как вы описываете, что под ключом `mid` может содержаться не ноль. Как было объяснено в комментариях, вы можете определить переменную, которая будет содержать эти самые данные при запросе:

```js
x.onload = function (){
    let mess = x.responseText;
}
```

И в дальнейшем работать уже с этой переменной `mess`. И вот вам пример, что произойдет если вы получите данные, где `mid` не равен нулю. Так же я добавлю еще что нибудь, чтобы вы понимали, что можете писать любую логику, которая вам нужна

```js
let mess = '{"mid":"что здесь???","id_1":123,"id":111}';
let mesJson = JSON.parse(mess);
let mid = mesJson["mid"];
if (mid == 0) {
  console.log("mid равен нулю");
} else {
  console.log("mid равен: " + mid + "\n и здесь я могу написать все что захочу или вместо вывода в консоль, вызвать какую нибудь функцию");
  let example = new Date;
  console.log(example.toISOString() + " - В это время я получил не ноль в ключе mid");
}
```

Comment: А если не выводить alert, как получить нужное значение?

Comment: Присвойте значение переменной или константе `let example = mesJson["mid"]`

Comment: Значение mid может быть разным, мне необходимо реагировать когда GET запрос возвращает mid: "0"

Comment: Добавил ветку `if` в ответ

Comment: Dmitry, по вашему варианту, мне вообще не нужно делать GET запрос, объявил переменную и получай её значения)) В чем смысл то, или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @Влад ну так адаптируйте вариант под свои нужды, добавьте нужный вам запрос

Comment: @Влад из-за CORS политики мы все равно здесь данные не получим, остается верить вашим словам, что вы получаете строку `'{"mid":"0","id_1":123,"id":111}'` , видимо это строка у вас в `x.responseText`, представьте, что `let mess = x.responseText; //'{"mid":"0","id_1":123,"id":111}';` . И тогда все встанет на место!

Comment: Leonid, благодарю, буду пробовать.